# Como ficaria a conversão desse algoritmo de c para c#?

Tags: c#, conversão

Como posso converter esse algoritmo de c para c#?

```
int main () {
        char nome[50];
        float LIM=20, soma=0.0, media, mediaTurma;
        float a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j; 
        int x, y;
        for (x=0; x<=LIM;x++){
            printf("Digite o nome do aluno:\t");
            scanf("%s", nome);
            printf("\nNota 1:");
            scanf("%f", &a);
            printf("Nota 2:");
            scanf("%f", &;  
            printf("Nota 3:");
            scanf("%f", &c); 
            printf("Nota 4:");
            scanf("%f", &d); 
            printf("Nota 5:");
            scanf("%f", &e); 
            printf("Nota 6:");
            scanf("%f", &f); 
            printf("Nota 7:");
            scanf("%f", &g); 
            printf("Nota 8:");
            scanf("%f", &h); 
            printf("Nota 9:");
            scanf("%f", &i); 
            printf("Nota 10:");
            scanf("%f", &j);
            soma=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j;
            media=soma/10;
                   if (media>=5) {
                          printf("Aluno aprovado! Media %f\n", media);
                   }
                   else {
                          printf("Aluno reprovado! Media %f\n", media);
                   }
            printf("-----------------------------\n\n");
            }
      system("PAUSE");    
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma dica: O código está muito mal escrito, recomendo fazer com arrays, mas ok. Traduzi para o C# por você, só copiar e colar.

```
public static void Main()
{
    double soma=0, media;
    double a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
    for (int x=0; x<=20;x++){
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do aluno:\t");
        string nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 1.");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 2.");
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 3.");
        c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 4.");
        d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 5.");
        e = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 6.");
        f = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 7.");
        g = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 8.");
        h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 9.");
        i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Nota 10.");
        j = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        soma=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j;
        media=soma/10;
               if (media>=5) {
                      Console.WriteLine("Aluno {1} aprovado! Media {0}", media, nome);
               }
               else {
                      Console.WriteLine("Aluno {1} reprovado! Media {0}", media, nome);
               }
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------\n");
        }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, de forma bem direta e sem validações de input e otimizações de código ficaria assim:

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String nome;
            float LIM = 20;
            float soma = 0;
            float media;
            float mediaTurma;
            float a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
            int x, y;
            for (x = 0; x <= LIM; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do aluno:\t");
                nome = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\nNota 1:");
                a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 2:");
                b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 3:");
                c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 4:");
                d = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 5:");
                e = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 6:");
                f = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 7:");
                g = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 8:");
                h = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 9:");
                i = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Nota 10:");
                j = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                soma = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j;
                media = soma / 10;
                if (media >= 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Aluno aprovado! Media {0}\n", media));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Aluno reprovado! Media {0}\n", media));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dica, use 4 espaços em cada linha do código para ficar formatado.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um código utilizando List<> e uma Classe para Alunos, segue o código:

```
namespace CadastroAlunos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Lim = 2;
            double somaTurma = 0;
            double mediaTurma = 0;
            double mediaAluno = 0;
            List<Aluno> Turma = new List<Aluno>();
            Aluno obj;
            for (int i = 0; i< Lim; i++)
            {
                obj = new Aluno();
                Console.Write("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
                obj.Nome = Console.ReadLine();
                for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Nota " + x + ": ");
                    string nota = Console.ReadLine();
                    obj.Notas.Add(Convert.ToDouble(nota));
                }

                Turma.Add(obj);

                mediaAluno = obj.Media();
                if (mediaAluno >= 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aluno Aprovado! Média: " + mediaAluno);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aluno Reprovado! Média: " + mediaAluno);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(20, '-')+"\r\n\r\n");
            }

            foreach (Aluno a in Turma)
                somaTurma += a.Media();

            mediaTurma = somaTurma / Turma.Count;

            Console.WriteLine("Média da Turma: " + mediaTurma);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Aluno
    {
        public Aluno()
        {
            this.Notas = new List<double>();
        }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public List<double> Notas { get; set; }
        public double Media()
        {
            if (Notas != null && this.Notas.Count >0)
            {
                return this.Soma() / this.Notas.Count;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
        public double Soma()
        {
            if (Notas != null)
            {
                double retorno = 0;
                foreach (float i in this.Notas)
                {
                    retorno += i;
                }
                return retorno;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
    }
}
```